# The use of “comme” after transitive verbs such as “laisser”

Tags: sens, prépositions, compléments

The question is on *comme* in this excerpt from *L'étranger* de Camus :

> Peu après, le ciel s’est assombri et j’ai cru que nous allions avoir un orage d’été. Il s’est découvert peu à peu cependant. Mais le passage des nuées avait laissé sur la rue **comme** une promesse de pluie qui l’a rendue plus sombre.

Which is the correct reading?

1. *Laisser* is a transitive verb, *promesse* its object, and *comme* modifies (introduces, sets the tone for, etc.) *promesse*.  In this case, what does *comme* mean?  Would it be like *as it were* (preparing the reader for a figurative meaning to come)?
2. *Laisser* is intransitive and *comme* introduces an adverbial clause.  In this case, what does *laisser* mean?

Comment: The same thing happens in “J'ai comme un doute” or “Il y a comme un problème”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Mais le passage des nuées avait laissé sur la rue comme une promesse
>   de pluie qui l’a rendue plus sombre.

Yes, you are right,  *Laisser* is, indeed,  a transitive verb, but this phrase does *ne suit pas une structure de topicalisation syntaxique au sens strict*. I mean that its object (complément d'objet direct) is not explicit.

If you try to put an explicit object to that verb (laisser), the phrase can be written this way:

> Mais le passage des nuées avait laissé sur la rue ***quelque chose*** comme une promesse
>   de pluie qui l’a rendue plus sombre.

Does this mean Camus was wrong? No. The phrase is correct, and it is common to findd implicite objects in French language. I give you a simple example:

> J'aime beaucoup

*aimer* is a transitive verb,  you can not see its object but still this phrase it correct. You can write it, depending on the context, for example like this: *j'aime beaucouo le dessin*

Comment: Thanks. It seems to match the usage of *like* as in: "He had *like* this skin disease or something."  But in English, *like* there sounds almost like *you know* or *uh*, and no one would re-write it as *something like*. So I gather from your answer that *comme* as in Camus is not so informal as *like*.

Comment: Exactly: this use of `comme` is poetic in French.  Translating it as `like`in English keeps the sense but completely reverses the tone.